# How to create simple UI tree structure using JSON data

Tags: angularjs

In JSON Description field is empty it should be created a root element and placed to top of the list.
If description filed is not empty the description name should be created folder name and title should be a document of the folder.
When same description name is coming again the title should be created a document of same folder description.

**Root Doc 1**(This is for description field should be empty)

**Root Doc2**

**Folder 1** (if description name not empty created as folder name as description and created doc1.1 as title)

**Doc 1.1**

**Doc 1.2** (if same description name like Folder 1 is coming again the description should not be created as folder and created as document like Doc1.2 as matched description)

**Folder 2**

**Doc 2.1**

**Doc 2.2**

HMTL File:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<ul ng-repeat="x in names">
<li ng-repeat="y in x.bookmarks" > 
    <span ng-if="y.description ==''">{{y.title}}</span>
    <span ng-if="y.description !==''">{{y.description}}
    <ul>
    <li>{{y.title}}</li>
    </ul>
    </span>
  </li>

</ul>

</div>
```

JS File:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{
    "description": "Testing File",
    "totalCount": 6,
    "bookmarks": [{
            "title": "Google",
            "link": "https://www.google.co.in",
            "description": "Health Care",
            "id": "3ee078ae-0f2e-48bf-9acc-535a753513d7",
            "tags": [
                "care", "child", "health"
            ],
            "createdDate": "Thu, 25 Feb 2016 08:23:01 -0600",
            "date": "Thu, 25 Feb 2016 09:32:53 -0600",
            "dateMillis": "1456414373315",
            "author": "test@gmail.com",
            "displayName": "Test Bookmark",
            "userid": "DIN2323",
            "contributorCount": 1,
            "isInternal": 0,
            "requiresHttpAuth": 0
        },

        {
            "title": "Test Construction1",
            "link": "http://google.com",
            "description": "",
            "id": "306dac71-a602-4e47-9b97-2cde7e72f76b",
            "tags": [
                "con", "concrete", "construction"
            ],
            "createdDate": "Thu, 25 Feb 2016 05:57:23 -0600",
            "date": "Thu, 25 Feb 2016 08:25:46 -0600",
            "dateMillis": "1456410346467",
            "author": "test@gmail.com",
            "displayName": "Test Bookmark",
            "userid": "DIN2323",
            "contributorCount": 1,
            "isInternal": 0,
            "requiresHttpAuth": 0
        },
        {
        "title": "Project EA TEST 1",
        "link": "http://sample.com",
        "description": "",
        "id": "5e19e314-ddaf-4041-a516-8fea14b1e90b",
        "tags": [
            "1.1.concrete", "1.construction"
        ],
        "createdDate": "Thu, 25 Feb 2016 00:21:17 -0600",
        "date": "Thu, 25 Feb 2016 06:17:39 -0600",
        "dateMillis": "1456402659864",
        "author": "test@gmail.com",
        "displayName": "Test Bookmark",
        "userid": "DIN2323",
        "contributorCount": 2,
        "isInternal": 0,
        "requiresHttpAuth": 0
    }, {
        "title": "Project EA TEST 3",
        "link": "http://sample.com",
        "description": "Construction",
        "id": "9c31fdb4-bd83-4679-8c6c-66ae93d5db61",
        "tags": [
            "construction-concrete"
        ],
        "createdDate": "Thu, 25 Feb 2016 00:18:17 -0600",
        "date": "Thu, 25 Feb 2016 00:18:17 -0600",
        "dateMillis": "1456381097393",
        "author": "test@gmail.com",
        "displayName": "Test Bookmark",
        "userid": "DIN2323",
        "contributorCount": 1,
        "isInternal": 0,
        "requiresHttpAuth": 0
    }, {
        "title": "Test Construction",
        "link": "https://google.com",
        "description": "Construction",
        "id": "46c20ef9-4455-4248-a21e-6299bd22ba0b",
        "tags": [
            "care", "health"
        ],
        "createdDate": "Wed, 24 Feb 2016 09:27:20 -0600",
        "date": "Thu, 25 Feb 2016 06:33:53 -0600",
        "dateMillis": "1456403633944",
        "author": "test@gmail.com",
        "displayName": "Test Bookmark",
        "userid": "DIN2323",
        "contributorCount": 1,
        "isInternal": 0,
        "requiresHttpAuth": 0
    }, {
        "title": "Test Connection",
        "link": "https://www.google.com",
        "description": "Education",
        "id": "6952bada-567b-47a5-a480-4c5394e694c2",
        "tags": [
            "manufacturing", "roofing"
        ],
        "createdDate": "Wed, 24 Feb 2016 09:23:52 -0600",
        "date": "Wed, 24 Feb 2016 09:23:52 -0600",
        "dateMillis": "1456327432494",
        "author": "test@gmail.com",
        "displayName": "Test Bookmark",
        "userid": "DIN2323",
        "contributorCount": 1,
        "isInternal": 0,
        "requiresHttpAuth": 0
    }
    ]

}];
});
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: is names an array or object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the unique description names and then use two ng-repeat loops.
use unique descriptions in outer loop and in inner loop filter all bookmarks using outer loop value.

you can check the implementation [here](http://jsbin.com/qobonujaqu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: But extra null list item was created in this example

Comment: And how if description null item should be in top the list item

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam check the updated jsbin. Corrected the format and ordered empty discription nodes top.

Comment: Thanks For rply . pls guide me how to add logic ( If description comes as "one > two" like as "two" was created a sub folder of "one" and "title" should be created as "document" of two. ) from your script

Comment: In this script If descriptions should be empty created a list but it also created a empty <ul>

Comment: pls Guide me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699451/how-to-add-a-logic-in-custom-filters-for-created-tree-structure

Comment: Thanks For rply . pls guide me how to add logic ( If description comes as "one > two" like as "two" was created a sub folder of "one" and "title" should be created as "document" of two. ) from your script

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam it not fair. I answered your question.It solved then you asked more functionality in that..you created new question for that too.but why unaccepted this answer which already solved the problem you mentioned in this question.

Comment: Sry pavan I feel if unaccepted mean any one help to solve this issue. So that I changed pls don't mine it

Comment: I'm using your script on my project in this script I'm try to add new functionality I'm hardly try but I didn't archive this pls help me resolve this issue

Comment: i am little busy today.can see tomorrow .

Comment: OK pavan . thanks in advance . I'm strongly believe you are the correct person to solve this issue.

Comment: Any luck regarding this approach

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a custom logic for that particular scenario you might want to have a look at https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree. I think it has everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for rply . We are planning to not use any plugins .

Comment: Cool man. Good luck then. You might just want to create a view model and use it to populate your view. I would do it as a service to keep it clean.